# Python | (Tkinter) only shows text when button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

So I made a button to copy something to clipboard, but the button itself is always showing, but the text on it only when its pressed, how to fix it?
(Here the part with the button code:)

```
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()


def copy_button():
    clip = tk.Tk()
    clip.withdraw()
    clip.clipboard_clear()
    clip.clipboard_append(pw)
    clip.destroy()


button1 = tk.Button(text="Copy to Clipboard", command=copy_button, bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)
```

Comment: Is the text getting clipped?  Does it work if you change the text to `"Copy"`?

Comment: Is this happening on a Mac, by any chance?  I've seen various reports of blank button text, but I'm not seeing any definite solution to the problem.

Comment: Yeah, using PyCharm on MacOS.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, if I click the button, the text is getting into my clipboard & the text appears. As long as I don't press the button, nothing is getting copied and no text is there.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have two instances of Tk. Change `clip = tk.Tk()` to `clip = tk.Toplevel()`

Comment: @Henry okay thanks I will try that as soon as I get back home (around 4h from now), will write a comment again then.

Answer (score 0):

Your disappearing text issue does not appear in Linux OS but I suspect your issue is related to your `button1 = tk.Button(....)` statement.

The first argument to a `tk.Button` widget **must be its parent** (see this [link](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html) on this requirement) and not a keyword/option.

Try `button1 = tk.Button(canvas1, text="Copy to Clipboard", ....)`. Doing so, you define the `tk.Button` to be a child of the `tk.Canvas` widget.

If you are putting more than a button in the canvas, you might want to consider:

1. defining a `tk.Frame` to be a child of the `tk.Canvas`(e.g. `frame1=tk.Frame(canvas1)`),
2. replace `window=button1` with `window=frame1`,
3. letting button1 to be a child of frame1, e.g. `button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Copy to Clipboard", ....)`

Do let me know if this answer addresses your issue.

Other suggestion:

You can remove  `clip = tk.Tk()`, `clip.withdraw()`, `clip.destroy()` and replace the `clip` term in `clip.clipboard_clear()` and `clip.clipboard_append(pw)` with `root`. Here, I assume that you had earlier defined `root = tk.Tk()` at the start of your code.